# http statusCode sometimes undefined

Tags: node.js, http, express, request

I'm using request module in my node.js(express) application. Sometimes this statusCode related error occurs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property
'statusCode' of undefined at Request._callback
```

This is my whole code:

```
request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=" + docs[0].title + "&type=video&key=(some-key-variable)", {
                json: true
              }, function(error, response, resultData) {
                var yArr = [];
                if (!error || response.statusCode == 200) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < config.youtubeVideoCount; i++) {
                    var vArr = resultData.items[i];
                    yArr.push(vArr);
                  }
                } else {
                  console.log("can't find video");
                }
              });
```

`response.statusCode` gives an error sometimes. How can I control that the request is successful? Is it bug in the request module? Why is statusCode undefined sometimes? I think statusCode should be available every time.

**Answer**
Probably it is response timeout issue and u should do an if statement like this;

```
if (response === undefined || response.statusCode != 200){ console.log("there is a prob"); }
```

this code firstly control response variable and then response.statuscode , so if response undefined don't control response.statusCode thus , we can't get any error.

Comment: If the error is truthy then `response` my be undefined but it will still check `response.statusCode`

Comment: When statusCode is undefined, what is the value of readyState? I have seen browser environments that (incorrectly) don't set a status value until readyState is 2 or greater.

Comment: there is no readyState property into response , console log was undefined everyime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a workaround, as there might be several reasons why `response` is `undefined`:

```
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    // do your stuff here..
}
```

Comment: What reasons can be ?

Comment: @OsmanErdi, there can be many, e.g timeout issues, bugs in implementation and a bunch of others. In any case you should use a workaround to be clear

Comment: i discovered that error parameter in request  module controls response undefined or null , if null or undefined , return error because of this , we should write error control at top pf if statement ex; if (error || response.statusCode != 200) it is true

Comment: @OsmanErdi,, edited, correct the error argument describes and signifies any errors in the request, howevr i think this bis what you need `if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)`, since you need to run your code when no error exists and the request is indeed found (200 statusCode)

Comment: How could
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
be a workaround when 
    response 
can be undefined?