# With https how can I conditionalize against the status code of undefined?

Tags: node.js, https, undefined

Trying to test a HTTP status code in a module but my first response is always `undefined`:

*foo.js*

```
const pass = require('./bar')
const test = pass('https://www.google.com/') // URL for testing will be API URL

console.log(`The return is: ${test}`)
```

*bar.js*

**attempt 1:**

```
module.exports = (url) => {
  https
    .get(url, (res) => {
      console.log(res.statusCode)
      if (typeof res.statusCode !== 'undefined' && res.statusCode.toString()[0] === '2') {
       console.log(`Results: ${res.statusCode}`)
       return true
      }
      function waiting(status) {
        if (typeof status !== 'undefined') {
          console.log('run timeout')
          setTimeout(waiting, 250)
        } else {
          console.log(`Results: ${status}`)
          return true
        }
      }
    })
    .on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(`Error ${e}`)
      return false
    })
}
```

**attempt 2:**

```
module.exports = (url) => {
  https
    .get(url, (res) => {
      console.log(res.statusCode)
      function waiting(status) {
        if (typeof status !== 'undefined') {
          console.log('run timeout')
          setTimeout(waiting, 250)
        } else {
          console.log(`Results: ${status}`)
          return true
        }
      }
    })
    .on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(`Error ${e}`)
      return false
    })
}
```

**other attempts to detect `undefined`:**

```
if (typeof res.statusCode === 'number' && res.statusCode !== undefined && res.statusCode !== null) {

if (!res.statusCode) {

if (typeof res.statusCode !== 'undefined') {
  console.log(`Results: ${res.statusCode}`)
  if (res.statusCode.toString()[0] === '2') return true
  return false
}
```

**Research:**

- [http get NodeJS how to get error status code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712392/http-get-nodejs-how-to-get-error-status-code)
- [JavaScript checking for null vs. undefined and difference between == and ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and)
- [http statusCode sometimes undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752225/http-statuscode-sometimes-undefined/29752342)

What am I doing wrong? In my module how can I check the status code *after* the `undefined` so I can return a `true` or `false` from the actual numerical value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both your attempts, your exported function in bar.js is not returning anything. Since you are calling an async function (`https.get`), you will need your exported function to be async as well. You can convert your function use promises and use async/await on the calling side. E.g.

foo.js

```
const pass = require('./bar');

(async function() {
    const test = await pass('https://www.google.com/'); // URL for testing will be API URL

    console.log(`The return is: ${test}`);
})();
```

Note the IFEE to get an async scope, as per: [using await on global scope without async keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525234/using-await-on-global-scope-without-async-keyword)

bar.js

```
const https = require('https');

module.exports = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https
        .get(url, (res) => {
            console.log(res.statusCode)
            if (typeof res.statusCode !== 'undefined' && res.statusCode.toString()[0] === '2') {
                console.log(`Results: ${res.statusCode}`)
                resolve(true)
            } else {
                resolve(false)
            }
        })
        .on('error', (e) => {
            console.error(`Error ${e}`)
            resolve(false)
        })
    });
}
```

**Alternatively**, you can use a callback as follows:

foo.js

```
const pass = require('./bar');

pass('https://www.google.com/', test => {
    console.log(`The return is: ${test}`);
});
```

bar.js

```
const https = require('https');

module.exports = (url, callback) => {
    https
    .get(url, (res) => {
        console.log(res.statusCode)
        if (typeof res.statusCode !== 'undefined' && res.statusCode.toString()[0] === '2') {
            console.log(`Results: ${res.statusCode}`)
            callback(true)
        } else {
            callback(false)
        }
    })
    .on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(`Error ${e}`)
        callback(false)
    })
}
```

Comment: In case anyone does want to use the Async function approach be aware some [Prettier settings](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/2800) will require it to be written as `;(async function() { // code})()`.